# TinyMCE 5 - How to get a progress bar when uploading videos

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

I am trying to polish the video upload process for my TinyMCE setup.

I have managed to get the videos to upload via my upload script (as opposed to uploading as a blob) by using the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/68182918

I would like to have a progress bar shown when uploading. Based on https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/upload-images/#images_upload_handler I tried to add

```
xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
    progress(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
};
```

from within the `file_picker_callback` function, after the `xhr.open('POST', '/your-endpoint');` line, but I just get errors that `progress is not defined`, because the `progress` callback does not get passed to `file_picker_callback`.

How can I show a progress bar (presumably one built in to TinyMCE) for the upload from `file_picker_callback`?